# I'm trying to create a countdown timer, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, timer

I'm trying to make a Python programmed timer; is anything wrong here?

```
#CTimer

import os;
import time

#vl

repeater = 2

sleeptime = 0.00

#code

while repeater==2:
print("-CTimer-")
print("\n")
print("Set time")
print("Use preset")
print("Exit")
print("\n")
var1 = input(">>>")

if var1=="set time":

    sleeptime = input("Set time:")

    start = input("Start")

    time.sleep(sleeptime)

    os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat")

if var1=="use preset":

    print("1min")
    print("5min")
    print("10min")
    print("20min")
    print("30min")
    print("45min")
    print("1hour")
    print("\n")
    usepreset = input("Use preset:")

    if usepreset=="1min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(60)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="5min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(300)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="10min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(600)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="20min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(1200)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="30min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(1800)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="45min":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(2700)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if usepreset=="1hour":

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(3600)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

if var1=="exit":

    print("Exiting...")

    time.sleep(5)

    exit()
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: *If you notice anything wrong* - that's not how this site works

Comment: what is not working? Can your add indentation in code?

Comment: Well if *"it doesn't work"* then yeah, something's *"wrong wrong"*

Comment: Tell me the indentation I need to fix.....

Comment: by the way this code is simplified...

Comment: Error code when I run this code in the Python Shell 3.4...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ctimer.py", line 30, in <module>
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
TypeError: a float is required

Comment: @CodeCreeper Yes just ran your code. `sleeptime = 0.00`  set this to int i.e. `sleeptime = 0` and run again, let me know if it is working for not

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ctimer.py", line 30, in <module>
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
TypeError: a float is required

Comment: Apology. not checked code. Do Type Casting `sleeptime =input("Set time:")` in this line. i.e. `sleeptime = int(input("Set time:"))`

Comment: ok... ill try that as well...no need to apologise :)

Comment: it says a `float` is required, so do: `sleeptime = float(input("Set time:"))`

Comment: error code: does raw_input() need to be defined? isn't it defined already?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ctimer.py", line 10, in <module>
    sleeptime =raw_input("Set time:")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: use `input()` for Python 3.x. I am using Python 2.7 so I used ` raw_input()`

Comment: or... sleeptime = raw_input("Set time:")

Comment: instead of... sleeptime =raw_input() I think u missed the whitespace there

Comment: no, its still not working...

Comment: oh ok... that might work im using Python 3.4...

Comment: now what is exception? or can you shear you py file on my email vivekbsable@gmail.com with how your are runing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just had to add `float()` to make your `sleeptimer` variable readable by the `time.sleep()` function:

```
#CTimer

import os;
import time

#vl

repeater = 2

sleeptime = 0.00

#code

while repeater==2:
    print("-CTimer-")
    print("\n")
    print("Set time")
    print("Use preset")
    print("Exit")
    print("\n")
    var1 = input(">>>")

    if var1=="set time":

        sleeptime = float(input("Set time:"))  #<-- add float()

        start = input("Start")

        time.sleep(sleeptime)

        os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat")

    if var1=="use preset":

        print("1min")
        print("5min")
        print("10min")
        print("20min")
        print("30min")
        print("45min")
        print("1hour")
        print("\n")
        usepreset = input("Use preset:")

        if usepreset=="1min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(60)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="5min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(300)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="10min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(600)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="20min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(1200)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="30min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(1800)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="45min":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(2700)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

        if usepreset=="1hour":

            start = input("Start")

            time.sleep(3600)

            os.system("C:/Python34/Scripts/alsctimer64an.bat");

    if var1=="exit":

        print("Exiting...")

        time.sleep(5)

        exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Type Casting**

Need to do Type Casting of user enter value. Because data type of `sleeptime` variable is string and `time.sleep()` method need float or int. So do Type Casting.

Demo:

```
>>> import time
>>> sleeptime = raw_input("Set time:")
Set time:1.2
>>> sleeptime
'1.2'
>>> type(sleeptime)
<type 'str'>
>>> time.sleep(sleeptime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
>>> time.sleep(float(sleeptime))
>>>
```

---

**Exception Handling during Type Casting**

User might enter wrong value, so add exception Handling code during Type Casting.

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     sleeptime = float(raw_input("Set time:"))
... except ValueError:
...     print "Value Error, Enter only float value"
...     sleeptime = 0.0
... 
Set time:we
Value Error, Enter only float value
>>> try:
...     sleeptime = float(raw_input("Set time:"))
... except ValueError:
...     print "Value Error, Enter only float value"
...     sleeptime = 0.0
... 
Set time:10.1
>>> print sleeptime, type(sleeptime)
10.1 <type 'float'>
>>>
```

---

Use **if-elif-else** loop

Demo:

```
if usepreset=="1min":
    pass
    #code
elif usepreset=="5min":
    pass
    #code
elif usepreset=="10min":
    pass
    #code
else:
    print ("Enter Wrong Input.")
```

---

No need of extra variable `repeater = 2`, use `True` or `1` or any true value (Not not use `0`, `False`, `''`)

```
While True:
   # add your code.
```

---

In code, do Type casting at following line

```
sleeptime = float(input("Set time:"))
             ^^^
```

---

**Note:**

Use input() for Python 3.x

Use raw_input() for Python 2.x

Comment: doing    sleeptime = input("Set time:")    here prints "Set time:" at the start, then shows the menu, I input "set time".

Comment: i set the time, eg.4.00

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Scripts\ctimer.py", line 30, in <module>
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
TypeError: a float is required

Comment: yes, the data type of `sleeptime` is string and `time.sleep()` method need float.  Just do `sleeptime = float(input("Set time:"))` or `time.sleep(float(sleeptime))`

Comment: @CodeCreeper: Best pass me your code- vivekbsable@gmail.com